# What is a good way to get rid of fireflies in renders? (cycles render)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I was rendering some scenes and the little white dots just don't go away. I find they are primarily there when i have some light shining on glass or even just a normal diffuse. Lots of people say different things. BlenderGuru says put the 'Indirect Clamp' up, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad, and fireflies can be caused by many things. Try sharing your blend file so that people can give answers that'll actually help you (rather than resorting to guessing).

Answer (score 0):

Use the lastest version of Bleder 2.79.

You can find a denoising panel.

See the image:

See the link in [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/denoising.html).

[image]